# Presto URL Functions

Tags: sql, presto

I need to pull urls from a database, re-formatting them slightly in the process. Some of the URLs in the db have port numbers specified, some don't. I'm using Presto's handy [URL extraction functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/url.html), such as url_extract_port.

However, when the following sql encounters a url where no port is specified, it returns null - even for rows that are not in fact null. (If I remove the url_extract_port function I get the link value, but without the port.)

```
SELECT
  concat(
    url_extract_protocol(link)
    ,'://'
    ,url_extract_host(link)
    ,':'
    ,cast(url_extract_port(link) AS VARCHAR)
  )
   AS  url
 FROM db.schema.urltable
WHERE link is not null
```

Is there a way to specify in the sql that i only want to use url_extract_port when a port is specified?

Comment: a case expression? `case when url_extract_port(link) > 0 then x else y end`

Comment: A good idea. But I'm also wondering now if coalesce(value1, value2) might be good here. Except the 2nd value would be blank. Though maybe that's ok.

Comment: Specifically, I'll try cast(coalesce(url_extract_port(link),"")).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html) function solves the problem, with the *url_extract_port* line changed to:

```
,coalesce(cast(url_extract_port(link) AS VARCHAR),'')
```

In cases where the port is not present, *url_extract_port* returns null. Thus, when used as shown with coalesce, the default value, in this case an empty string, is returned instead.